# Dúvida sobre mapeamento com Java

Tags: spring-jpa

Criei um projeto colocando autenticação do sistema incluindo o login e senha direto no código Java, mas eu sei que isso está super errado, o mais recomendado para implementação de autenticação é o sistema buscar o login e senha direto do banco, além da autenticação o usuário também precisará de permissão, ou seja, não significa que ao logar o usuário terá direto de visualizar as paginas, as regras de navegabilidade vou colocar no Spring Security, o que está sendo complicado para mim é realizar o mapeamento nas entidade nas classes Java.

Eu sei realizar a criação do banco através de SQL, mas não sei como abstrair isso para mapeamento de entidade em Java, veja o modelo que construir em SQL;

Entidade **Usuário**;

```
CREATE TABLE usuario (
    codigo BIGINT(20) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nome VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    senha VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Entidade **Grupo**;

```
CREATE TABLE grupo (
    codigo BIGINT(20) PRIMARY KEY,
    nome VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Entidade **Permissao**;

```
CREATE TABLE permissao (
    codigo BIGINT(20) PRIMARY KEY,
    nome VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Entidade **GrupoPermissao**;

```
CREATE TABLE grupopermissao (
    codigo_grupo BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    codigo_permissao BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (codigo_grupo, codigo_permissao),
    FOREIGN KEY (codigo_grupo) REFERENCES grupo(codigo),
    FOREIGN KEY (codigo_permissao) REFERENCES permissao(codigo)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Entidade **UsuarioGrupo**;

```
CREATE TABLE usuariogrupo (
    codigo_usuario BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    codigo_grupo BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (codigo_usuario, codigo_grupo),
    FOREIGN KEY (codigo_usuario) REFERENCES usuario(codigo),
    FOREIGN KEY (codigo_grupo) REFERENCES grupo(codigo)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Vou fazer uma explicação das minhas intenções em relação a essas tabelas acima, as tabelas iriam se comportar da seguinte forma.

No sistema o usuário iria entrar na tela de cadastro permissões e iria cadastrar somente duas permissões;

- VISUALIZAR_CADASTRO
- VISUALIZAR_PESQUISA

Depois o o usuário iria entrar na tela de cadastro de grupos e iria cadastrar somente dois grupos;

- Administradores
- Vendedores

Em seguida o usuário iria entra numa tela de cadastro de associar os grupos para as permissões, ai você imagina você entrar numa tela com dois **ComboBox**, uma iria listar os grupos e o outro listar as permissões, depois de escolher iria somente sobmeter o formulário nessa tela.

se administradores fosse código 1 e vendedores fosse código 2 então permissõe de cadastrar fosse código 1 e visualizar pesquisas fosse código 2 iria ficar mais ou menos assim;

GrupoPermissao

- 1,1
- 1,2
- 2,1

Isso quer dizer que administrador estaria no grupo que tem permissão para pesquisar e cadastrar e grupo de vendedores somente de cadastrar.

Me desculpe a postagem longa, mas era necessária para entenderem meu contexto.

A minha única dificuldade é que eu não sei como devo mapear minhas entidades em relação a realidade descrita logo a cima, não sei nem pra onde ir.

Comment: Oi wladyband. Não sei se entendi a dúvida direito, porém para mim me  parece que você tem duas relações `@ManyToMany`, ou seja, se quiser manear isso com JPA você terá uma entidade `Grupo` com uma `List<Usuario>` e uma `List<Permisao>`. Do lado da `Permisao` e do `Usuario` você terá uma `List<Grupo>`. Veja porém que se você vai utilizar o Spring Security, não há motivo para inventar a roda. Ele tem o esquema de [Group Authorities](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#group-authorities) e o `UserDetailsService`.

Answer (score 0):

Para mapear as entidades com o JPA, basta criar uma classe representado a entidade e os atributos da classe vão representar as colunas. Vou deixar aqui um exemplo do mapeamento da sua entidade `usuario`. Para as demais entidades, consulte este guia e ele te ajudará a seguir (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jpa/)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USUARIO")
public class Usuario implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "codigo")
    private Long codigo;

    @Column(name = "EMAIL", nullable = false, unique=true)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "SENHA", nullable = false)
    private String senha;
}
```

Para implementar os diferentes níveis de acesso de cada usuário, o Spring Security oferece uma série de validações e métodos auxiliadores, veja nesse guia (http://www.baeldung.com/role-and-privilege-for-spring-security-registration). A grosso modo você vai precisar mapear as entidades que representam os *ROLES* de cada usuário ou grupo de usuário e vai utilizá-los como permissões.

---

Seu problema é bem comum e, com um pouco de pesquisa sobre mapeamento de entidades com JPA e restrições de acesso com Spring Security, você conseguirá seguir.

Espero ter ajudado. Vou deixar aqui alguns links que podem ser úteis.

- [Guias e documentação do Spring Security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/)
- [Introdução ao JPA](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jpa/jpa_introduction.htm)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, o que estou tendo dificuldade mesmo é saber como ficara as entidade grupopermissao e usuariogrupo.

Comment: Oi @wladyband, não sei se você viu o meu comentário. Como esse *schema* não possui atributos de relacionamento não há necessidade de mapear essas tabelas como entidade. Você pode fazer o mapeamento com [`@ManyToMany`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany) e `@JoinTable`.